# Apache Camel support for dotnet

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-k

I am not finding any references on dotnet as a supported language for Camel. Though chatGPT says yes :). https://camel.apache.org/camel-k/next/languages/languages.html Is DotNet supported for handling Camelet sink and sources ?

[image]

Comment: This question is only a few months old when I'm posting this comment but that path no longer exists in the github repo and I can't find any history of it existing.  ChatGPT is 
 confidently wrong again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Apache Camel .Net project. Apache Camel is written in Java and runs on JVM. However you can use other languages with Camel such as JavaScript, Groovy, Kotlin, Python etc.

But there is no .Net support from Apache Camel project.

There could be integration frameworks written in .Net that resemble Apache Camel.